# Calculate the volume of the set

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Calculate the volume of the set

$$\\ E=\Big \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}: x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 1, \ \sqrt{2} (x^2+y^2) \le z \le \sqrt{6} (x^2+y^2)  \Big \}$$

I consider the cylindrical coordinates:

$$x= \rho \ cos \theta \\
y= \rho \ sin \theta \\
z=z \\ $$

So, I have to solve this system of inequalities to determine the boundaries:

$$\sqrt{2} \rho^2 \le z \le \sqrt{6} \rho^2 \\
\rho^2+z^2 \le 1$$ 

$$\rho^2+6 \rho^4 \le 1  \\  t=\rho^2 \\ 6t^2+t-1 \le 0 \\  -\frac{1}{2} \le t \le \frac{1}{3}  \\  -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \le \rho \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} 
$$

$$\rho^2+2 \rho^4 \le 1  \\ t=\rho^2 \\ 2t^2+t-1 \le 0 \\  -1 \le t \le \frac{1}{2}  \\  -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \le \rho \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $$

I consider that $\rho \ge 0 $:

$$F=\Big \{(\theta,\rho,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}: 0 \le \theta \le 2\pi, 0 \le \rho \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, \sqrt{2} \rho^2 \le z \le \sqrt{6} \rho^2  \Big \} $$

$$
\int_0^{2\pi} ( \int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}} (\int_{\sqrt{2} \rho^2 }^{\sqrt{6} \rho^2} \rho \, dz ) \, d\rho ) \,d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi} ( \int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}} (\sqrt{6} \ \rho^3-\sqrt{2} \ \rho^3) \, d\rho ) \,d\theta=
$$ 
 
 $$
=\int_0^{2\pi} \Big[\frac{\sqrt{6}}{4} \ \rho^4 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} \ \rho^4   \Big]^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}_0  \,d\theta= 2\pi \ (\frac{\sqrt{6}}{36} -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{36} )
$$

Is it correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Please use \pi, not \Pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $0<\rho<\frac1{\sqrt{3}}$, $z$ is between $\sqrt{2}\rho^2$ and $\sqrt{6}\rho^2$.
For $\frac1{\sqrt{3}}<\rho<\frac1{\sqrt{2}}$, $z$ is between $\sqrt{2}\rho^2$ and $\sqrt{1-\rho^2}$

Comment: Thanks! Therefore, how can I fix my problem?

Comment: You have already done the integral for $\rho$ between 0 and $1/\sqrt{3}$.  Now do do the different integral for $\rho$ between $1/\sqrt{3}$ and $1/\sqrt{2}$.